# Reciprocal Polynomial

Tags: polynomials

I am studying the chapter of my book about transforming polynomials but I don't understand how the reciprocal polynomial is found.

This is an excerpt from my book :

> Let the given polynomial be $f(x)$ and the roots be $r_1,r_2,r_3,$ and
>   $r_4$. One equation whose solutions are the reciprocals of these is
>   just $f(1/x)=0$ because $f \left(\cfrac{1}{1/r_i}\right)=f(r_i)=0 $.

While it's okay why the function $f(1/x)$ should have the reciprocals of the roots of $f(x)$ ,I don't understand the explanation of this given by $f\left(\cfrac{1}{1/r_i}\right)=f(r_i)=0 $.

Can someone make it clear please ?

Comment: **HINT**: $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}}=1\div\frac{1}{a}=1\times\frac{a}{1}=a$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they mean is that the new function is called $F$. Such that:

$$ F(x) = f(\frac{1}{x})$$

Now

$$ F\left(\frac{1}{r_i}\right) = f\left(\frac{1}{1/r_i}\right) = f(r_i) = 0 $$

Comment: In your second step you're basically showing that if we take the reciprocal of the reciprocal roots we get back to the original equation ?

Comment: Yes ,it's all clear now.Thank you @Petar Ivanov.

Comment: Going back at this,I think I am making the concept harder than it needs to be.My first comment is the proof.We need only to show that in our new function $F(x)$ when we plug $1/r_i$ we get $0$. However there's still one point which is not clear to me.Namely we want to define $F(x)$ also as the function that when it takes the reciprocal of the reciprocal gets me back at the original function.So my question is: What is the right way of seeing it ?

Comment: I can't make sense of your comment - can you be more clear?

Comment: When you defined your function $F(x)$ you were looking for some functions such that $F(1/r_i)=0$. Once we defined this $F(x)$ ,shouldn't this function also take me back to my original function if I take $\cfrac {1}{1/r_i} $?Namely I am trying to "reverse" the process,from $F(x)$ I want to get back to $f(x)$ .

Comment: I still don't understand what you are saying... If you take $$G(x) = F(\frac{1}{x}) = f(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}) = f(x)$$. That's trivial.